# Python regular expression search vs match

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use a python regular expression to match 'BrahuiHan' or 'BrahuiYourba'

```
>> re.search(r'((Brahui|Han|Yoruba)+\d+)', '10xBrahuiHan50_10xBrahuiYoruba50n4').groups()

('BrahuiHan50', 'Han')
```

this only returns one group, the first one, I thought it should return  the second one too. i.e BrahuiYoruba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to capture all occurrences of a pattern, you need to use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'((Brahui|Han|Yoruba)+\d+)', '10xBrahuiHan50_10xBrahuiYoruba50n4')
[('BrahuiHan50', 'Han'), ('BrahuiYoruba50', 'Yoruba')]
>>>
```

`re.search` will only capture the first occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import re
regex = re.compile("((Brahui|Han|Yoruba)\\d{1,})")
testString = "" # fill this in
matchArray = regex.findall(testString)
# the matchArray variable contains the list of matches
```

Here is demo on [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/gupTwms9ZELyzGs1)

Pictorial representation:

[image]